# Spring error - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring

I want to allow a logged in user to access a page and automatically retrieve the modules assigned to them. So to that end I used the @PathVariable with the id as value.

My controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/main/user/setter/settingpage/{id}", method = 

    RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String showStaffModules(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap map, 

    HttpServletRequest request) {

           map.addAttribute("cp", request.getContextPath());

           map.addAttribute("Setter", userService.getWithModules(id));

           return "/main/user/setter/settingpage";
```

So far though an error keeps coming up:

```
    WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP 

    request with URI [/app/main/user/setter/settingpage] in DispatcherServlet with 

    name 'appServlet'
```

The page that is being requested is in the right location but it's not being returned. Would anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: The error message is far obvious. You're trying to send a request to this URL - `/app/main/user/setter/settingpage` whereas the request in your controller is actually mapped to the URL something like - `/main/user/setter/settingpage/10` which is indeed not available. Take of URL mapping.

Comment: Yeah I wanted the uri to return with the id of the user attached at the end, but I added another request mapping without the id. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the path variable in url `/app/main/user/setter/settingpage` so it's not valid. You should create another `RequestMapping` to match the url without the variable.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/main/user/setter/settingpage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

P.s. I assume you have a mapping on the controller that maps to `/app`